# aur key not found, attempting to locate packages that use that key

Tags: aur, pgp

i tried to do an upgrade today and got an error about 2 keys I am trying to figure out which packages are causing the error so I can either delete them or gather the key file for them.

```
downloading required keys...
:: Import PGP key 139B09DA5BF0D338, "David Runge 
<dvzrv@archlinux.org>"? [Y/n] y
error: key "139B09DA5BF0D338" could not be looked up remotely
:: Import PGP key F4AA4E0ED2568E87, "Jiachen YANG 
<farseerfc@archlinux.org>"? [Y/n] y
error: key "F4AA4E0ED2568E87" could not be looked up remotely
error: required key missing from keyring
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking for sometime more I finally found a page that answered how to fix the error.

https://arcolinux.com/fix-for-key-could-not-be-looked-up-remotely/

> Then we get this error about …
>
> Key “123456789” could not be looked up remotely.
>
> First thing we try is this
>
> sudo pacman-key --refresh-keys
> We get an error:
>
> gpg: keyserver refresh failed : Server indicated a failure
>
> Second thing we try is to update the archlinux-keyring but if you have followed the video than you see that there was no recent update of this package. It is very unlikely that a reinstall will fix our issue.
>
> sudo pacman -Sy archlinux-keyring
>
> sudo pacman -Syu
>
> Third attempt is to reset all pacman keys from this link on Arch Wiki.
>
> sudo pacman-key --init
> sudo pacman-key --refresh-keys

Comment: I have found due to various issues im having with my garuda install i have to run pacman -Sy archlinux-keyring --noconfirm && pacman -Su weekly to keep various parts up to date so this does not happen again.

Answer (score 0):

Using Arch for the first time today, and couldn't install anything because of this error. I got the keys installed another way:

```
# sudo pacman-key --populate
```

Based on [the official docs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Pacman/Package_signing#Verifying_the_master_keys).